# PythonXY on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, macports, pythonxy

How do you install PythonXY on Mac OSX Lion?

I got started. It should be able through macports but anyhow I cannot find the port pythonXY as described on the mac ports website.

Comment: Could you please explain why you think it's possible to install pythonxy using MacPorts? If possible with a reference to your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know pretty much about MAC neither pythonXY but there is a post written (Jule 23th, 2009) on the pythonxy wiki:

> a MacOS version is not scheduled - not because it 
>   won't be needed or useful, but because there is nobody out there to take care of a 
>   pythonxy-Mac project.

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=90)

Good luck,

Comment: dislike, but I guess there is no serious working solutions out there. Tried to install it but it is not very stable. Some of the PythonXY libraries however may be used without the whole framework. E.g. SciKit and SciKit-Learn work on mac, without pythonXY. I guess it is the best bet to only use single libraries or to use it on windows in a vm